# Flickering when navigating from screen with different background color in react navigation v6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

The navigation screens works fine when navigating with the same background color. But when I navigate to different background color there is a white flickering effect. I use React Navigation v6.

There is a lot of solution for same background color but I can't find a solution for this case.

I used the usual navigation code:

```
navigation.navigate('AnotherBGColorScreen')
```

Comment: any code related?